# Extract json data string with applescript

Tags: json, string, curl, applescript

I have almost the same problem.
I'm using the following syntax:

```
set LINK to ("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com")
set api to ("XXXXXXXXXXXX")
set secret to ("XXXXXXXXXXX")

set RR to do shell script "curl -u '" & api & ":" & secret & "' https:/XXXXXXXurl='" & LINK & "'"

tell application "JSON Helper"
    set RRR to (read JSON from RR)
end tell
```

and I get this :

> {results:{{tagging_id:missing value,
>   image:"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com",
>   tags:{{tag:"symbol", confidence:26.962820053101}, {tag:"art",
>   confidence:26.631685256958}, {tag:"graphic",
>   confidence:26.29425239563}, {tag:"design",
>   confidence:25.914730072022}, {tag:"icon", confidence:21.400810241699},
>   {tag:"cartoon", confidence:20.534477233887}, {tag:"drawing",
>   confidence:18.931232452393}, {tag:"decoration",
>   confidence:18.834970474243}, {tag:"silhouette",
>   confidence:17.404066085815}, {tag:"shape",
>   confidence:14.910034179688}, {tag:"element",
>   confidence:14.898452758789}, {tag:"sign", confidence:14.306094169617},
>   {tag:"ornament", confidence:13.806978225708}, {tag:"human",
>   confidence:13.510297775269}, {tag:"black",
>   confidence:13.444707870483}, {tag:"logo", confidence:13.409428596497},
>   {tag:"pattern", confidence:13.006916999817}, {tag:"retro",
>   confidence:12.30048751831}, {tag:"star", confidence:11.705702781677},
>   {tag:"color", confidence:11.694045066834}, {tag:"card",
>   confidence:11.57892036438}, {tag:"gold", confidence:11.519770622253},
>   {tag:"banner", confidence:11.03851890564}, {tag:"heat",
>   confidence:10.58930683136}, {tag:"blaze", confidence:10.454214096069},
>   {tag:"circle", confidence:10.329438209534}, {tag:"power",
>   confidence:10.084959030151}, {tag:"decorative",
>   confidence:10.032000541687}, {tag:"bright",
>   confidence:10.019249916077}, {tag:"orange", confidence:9.9829454422},
>   {tag:"concepts", confidence:9.782785415649}, {tag:"style",
>   confidence:9.65638256073}, {tag:"outline", confidence:9.480903625488},
>   {tag:"character", confidence:9.435729026794}, {tag:"floral",
>   confidence:9.367718696594}, {tag:"flower", confidence:9.236577987671},
>   {tag:"heraldry", confidence:9.019858360291}, {tag:"curve",
>   confidence:8.756514549255}, {tag:"love", confidence:8.692363739014},
>   {tag:"colorful", confidence:8.608165740967}, {tag:"leaf",
>   confidence:8.568987846375}, {tag:"3d", confidence:8.527961730957},
>   {tag:"fire", confidence:8.443150520325}, {tag:"hand",
>   confidence:8.4037733078}, {tag:"clip art", confidence:8.348271369934},
>   {tag:"heart", confidence:8.291186332703}, {tag:"backdrop",
>   confidence:8.250628471375}, {tag:"figure", confidence:8.186657905579},
>   {tag:"person", confidence:8.040968894958}, {tag:"yellow",
>   confidence:7.957674980164}, {tag:"colors", confidence:7.941210269928},
>   {tag:"frame", confidence:7.811089992523}, {tag:"golden",
>   confidence:7.745839118958}, {tag:"wallpaper",
>   confidence:7.666860580444}, {tag:"head", confidence:7.567168235779},
>   {tag:"paisley", confidence:7.478963375092}, {tag:"vintage",
>   confidence:7.451002120972}, {tag:"light", confidence:7.361023902893},
>   {tag:"ornate", confidence:7.328865528107}, {tag:"fantasy",
>   confidence:7.22393655777}, {tag:"cute", confidence:7.183915138245},
>   {tag:"holiday", confidence:7.175530433655}, {tag:"science",
>   confidence:7.122048377991}, {tag:"animal", confidence:7.087336540222},
>   {tag:"spring", confidence:7.072511672974}, {tag:"medical",
>   confidence:7.06857919693}}}}}

My problem is : I'm a newbie and I just want to get tags that have a confidence greater than 12. I would like to get something like this :

> symbol,art,graphic,design,icon,cartoon,drawing,decoration,[...]retro

What should I add at the end of my syntax ?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, I added comments to the lines, the result is in the variable `filteredTags` which is a list of strings.

```
set resultDict to {results:{{tagging_id:missing value, image:"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com", tags:{{tag:"symbol", confidence:26.962820053101}, {tag:"art", confidence:26.631685256958}, {tag:"graphic", confidence:26.29425239563}, {tag:"design", confidence:25.914730072022}, {tag:"icon", confidence:21.400810241699}, {tag:"cartoon", confidence:20.534477233887}, {tag:"drawing", confidence:18.931232452393}, {tag:"decoration", confidence:18.834970474243}, {tag:"silhouette", confidence:17.404066085815}, {tag:"shape", confidence:14.910034179688}, {tag:"element", confidence:14.898452758789}, {tag:"sign", confidence:14.306094169617}, {tag:"ornament", confidence:13.806978225708}, {tag:"human", confidence:13.510297775269}, {tag:"black", confidence:13.444707870483}, {tag:"logo", confidence:13.409428596497}, {tag:"pattern", confidence:13.006916999817}, {tag:"retro", confidence:12.30048751831}, {tag:"star", confidence:11.705702781677}, {tag:"color", confidence:11.694045066834}, {tag:"card", confidence:11.57892036438}, {tag:"gold", confidence:11.519770622253}, {tag:"banner", confidence:11.03851890564}, {tag:"heat", confidence:10.58930683136}, {tag:"blaze", confidence:10.454214096069}, {tag:"circle", confidence:10.329438209534}, {tag:"power", confidence:10.084959030151}, {tag:"decorative", confidence:10.032000541687}, {tag:"bright", confidence:10.019249916077}, {tag:"orange", confidence:9.9829454422}, {tag:"concepts", confidence:9.782785415649}, {tag:"style", confidence:9.65638256073}, {tag:"outline", confidence:9.480903625488}, {tag:"character", confidence:9.435729026794}, {tag:"floral", confidence:9.367718696594}, {tag:"flower", confidence:9.236577987671}, {tag:"heraldry", confidence:9.019858360291}, {tag:"curve", confidence:8.756514549255}, {tag:"love", confidence:8.692363739014}, {tag:"colorful", confidence:8.608165740967}, {tag:"leaf", confidence:8.568987846375}, {tag:"3d", confidence:8.527961730957}, {tag:"fire", confidence:8.443150520325}, {tag:"hand", confidence:8.4037733078}, {tag:"clip art", confidence:8.348271369934}, {tag:"heart", confidence:8.291186332703}, {tag:"backdrop", confidence:8.250628471375}, {tag:"figure", confidence:8.186657905579}, {tag:"person", confidence:8.040968894958}, {tag:"yellow", confidence:7.957674980164}, {tag:"colors", confidence:7.941210269928}, {tag:"frame", confidence:7.811089992523}, {tag:"golden", confidence:7.745839118958}, {tag:"wallpaper", confidence:7.666860580444}, {tag:"head", confidence:7.567168235779}, {tag:"paisley", confidence:7.478963375092}, {tag:"vintage", confidence:7.451002120972}, {tag:"light", confidence:7.361023902893}, {tag:"ornate", confidence:7.328865528107}, {tag:"fantasy", confidence:7.22393655777}, {tag:"cute", confidence:7.183915138245}, {tag:"holiday", confidence:7.175530433655}, {tag:"science", confidence:7.122048377991}, {tag:"animal", confidence:7.087336540222}, {tag:"spring", confidence:7.072511672974}, {tag:"medical", confidence:7.06857919693}}}}}

-- get the value for key `results`
set theResults to resultDict's results
-- check if the array is not empty
if (count theResults) = 0 then return
-- get the value for key `tags` of the first item of `theResults`
set theTags to theResults's first item's tags
-- create the list for the result
set filteredTags to {}
-- in the repeat loop get the value for key `confidence` and
-- add the tag to the result list if the value > 12
repeat with aTag in theTags
    if aTag's confidence > 12.0 then set end of filteredTags to aTag's tag
end repeat
```

Comment: I dissect your lines and it works very well. It seems so simple now that I have the answer. thank you very much @vadian ! :)